# HQL match string percentage

Tags: hql

Can I pull data based on percentage matched with string.

Let my Table is `Employee` having a column named `'empName'`

```
session.createQuery("from Employee where percentage(empName, :emp_name) >= 85 ");
query.setParameter("emp_name", "Tony");
```

Comment: What is your expected output exactly?

Comment: I would suggest that you write out the raw query you want, then try to port it to HQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just I want to know is there any query/function that returns matched percentage OR returns the row that greater than or equal to my expected percentage. In HQL / SQL.

Comment: So you want employees in the 85th percentile or higher?  You might have to write a raw query to do this.